# Occasional stop on PowerPoint Chart interactions through Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am having a few issues with the `ChartData` property and I am hoping you guys can help. The short version is that when running the code it just stops, usually when trying to open/close the `ChartData` property, at random. Then I click resume and it continues to run.

The longer version, I am trying to update PowerPoint presentation with about 30 slides from several workbooks that can be found on a server. When I run the code, it usually stops when interacting with the workbook behind the Chart.

I've tried with/without references, activating or selecting the ChartData parent objects beforehand, but I still get the same error:

> Method workbook object chartdata failed

[image: Method workbook object chartdata failed]

Am I missing something or does Excel not speak "correctly" PowerPoint ?

Now to the code:

```
Option Explicit

Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
Public ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Public ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Public ppShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Public ppChart As PowerPoint.Chart
Public ppChartData As PowerPoint.ChartData
Public ppSeries As PowerPoint.Series

Public Wb as Workbook

'...

Sub PPT_Slide2 ()

Dim sPathWb As String
Dim Wb_Chart As Workbook
Dim Ws_Chart As Worksheet

sPathWb = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\[server folder partial address]" 

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(sPathWb & "\file.xlsm")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


For Each ppShape In ppSlide.Shapes
    'ppShape.Select
    If ppShape.Name = "Chart 1" Then

        Set ppChart = ppShape.Chart
        Set ppChartData = ppChart.ChartData
        ppShape.Chart.ChartData.Activate
        Set Wb_Chart = ppChartData.Workbook
        Set Ws_Chart = Wb_Chart.Worksheets(1)
        Ws_Chart.Activate

        Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).ClearContents

        Windows(Wb.Name).Activate
        Wb.Sheets("Financial").Activate

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Set Rng = Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlToRight))
        Rng.Copy

        ppApp.Activate
        Ws_Chart.Activate
        Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Windows(Wb.Name).Activate

        Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Activate

        Set Rng = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(14, 0))
        Rng.Copy

        ppApp.Activate
        Ws_Chart.Activate
        Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Windows(Wb.Name).Activate

        Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Activate
        Set Rng = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(14, 0).End(xlToRight))

        Rng.Copy

        ppApp.Activate
        Ws_Chart.Activate
        Ws_Chart.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ppShape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Close True

        '--> refreshing the chart here; 
        'for whatever reason the PowerPoint Chart does not show the newly added values 
        'unless in debug mode or if I set a wait time

        With ppChart
            .ChartData.Activate
            .Refresh
            Sleep 100
            .ChartData.Workbook.Close
        End With

    End If
Next

Wb.Close False

Set Wb = Nothing
Set Ws_Chart = Nothing
Set Wb_Chart = Nothing
Set ppChartData = Nothing
Set ppChart = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: If the error is in this line `ppShape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Close True` try a `ppShape.Chart.ChartData.Activate` just right before. `ChartData` must be activated before use. Where worksheets are better used without activating at all just by its direct reference.

Comment: You can access the data behind the chart without activating or selecting the object.  Presentations("File Name").Slides(2).Shapes.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.sheets(1).Range("A1:A2:").value = Workbook("Excel file").Sheets(1).Range("A1:A2").value

Comment: @ Pᴇʜ it works when closing the Chart, but it still stops when opening one.

Comment: @mooseman I remember trying that one when I started the project, but I was receiving errors when pasting and it said it couldn't find the wb object to paste to. I assumed then that it's due to the presentation being at origin pre 2000s.

Comment: Pre 2000's?  Well that can lead to all kinds of problems.  You may want to update the presentation or you will constantly run into issues. But putting the version in your question would be a huge help.

Comment: `DoEvents` can sometimes help by making VBA stop to let other processes finish (processes like screen updating, window handling, etc.). Using Sleep or Wait doesn't help so much; they seem to stop everything, including the processes that haven't finished yet.

Comment: What I've found better than `DoEvents` is to abstract certain tasks into separate functions. I can't really tell how to do that in your code, since I haven't worked with the ChartData object very much (enough to know it can be painful).

Comment: @JonPeltier I've added `DoEvents` and it works for few runs, but if I run it several time, it still stops (memory leak perhaps ? I don't know). Still, I don't expect the user to run the code over and over for the same month. Thank you!

Comment: @mooseman It's not up to me unfortunately, but I did improve it as much as I could.